# Sanity check for Simple Threading library

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've created a library providing a `ThreadBlock` that has the following features:

- Aggregates results of all actions executed
- Provides for non-threaded warm up to prepare data for processing
- Provides for per-thread continuation actions
- Provides for per-block continuation actions

The code is located on [GitHub](https://github.com/gatewayprogrammingschool/simplethreading).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GPS.SimpleThreading.Blocks
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Parallel thread block class that provides for
    /// thread warmup, execution, and continuation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// ## Features
    /// * Allows capture of results of thread executions
    /// * Allows warmup action per data item before spawning thread
    /// * Allows continuation action per data item after executing thread
    /// * Allows continuation of the entire set
    /// </remarks>
    public sealed class ThreadBlock<TData, TResult>
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TData, (TData data, TResult result)?> _results =
            new ConcurrentDictionary<TData, (TData data, TResult result)?>();

        private readonly ConcurrentBag<TData> _baseList =
            new ConcurrentBag<TData>();

        private bool _locked;
        private readonly Func<TData, TResult> _action;
        private readonly Action<ICollection<(TData data, TResult result)?>> _continuation;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor accepting the action and block continuation.
        /// </summary>
        public ThreadBlock(
            Func<TData, TResult> action,
            Action<ICollection<(TData data, TResult result)?>> continuation = null)
        {
            _action = action;
            _continuation = continuation;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add single data item.
        /// </summary>
        public void Add(TData item)
        {
            if (!_locked) _baseList.Add(item);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds range of data items from an IEnumerable
        /// </summary>
        public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TData> collection)
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(collection, Add);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds range of data items from an ICollection.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddRange(ICollection<TData> collection)
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(collection, Add);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds range of data items from an IProducerConsumerCollection.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddRange(IProducerConsumerCollection<TData> collection)
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(collection, Add);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Maximum number of concurrent threads (default = 1).
        /// </summary>
        public int MaxDegreeOfParallelism { get; set; } = 1;

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes a data item from the block.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Remove(TData item)
        {
            TData itemToRemove;

            if (!_locked)
                return _baseList.TryTake(out itemToRemove);

            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Locks the data of the block, allowing processing.
        /// </summary>
        public void LockList()
        {
            _locked = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the action over the set of data.
        /// </summary>
        public void Execute(
            int maxDegreeOfParallelization = -1,
            Action<TData> warmupItem = null,
            Action<Task, (TData data, TResult result)?> threadContinuation = null)
        {
            if (!_locked) throw new NotLockedException();

            if (maxDegreeOfParallelization == -1)
            {
                maxDegreeOfParallelization = MaxDegreeOfParallelism;
            }

            if (maxDegreeOfParallelization < 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                    "Must supply positive value for either " +
                    $"{nameof(maxDegreeOfParallelization)} or " +
                    $"this.{nameof(MaxDegreeOfParallelism)}.");
            }

            var padLock = new object();
            var queue = new Queue<TData>(_baseList);
            var allTasks = new Dictionary<TData, Task>();

            int depth = 0;

            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                var item = queue.Dequeue();

                if (warmupItem != null) warmupItem(item);

                var task = new Task<TResult>(() => _action(item));

                task.ContinueWith((resultTask, data) =>
                {
                    var returnValue = ((TData, TResult)?)(data, resultTask.Result);

                    if (threadContinuation != null)
                    {
                        threadContinuation(resultTask, returnValue);
                    }

                    _results.AddOrUpdate(item, returnValue,
                        (itemData, resultTaskResult) => resultTaskResult);

                    lock (padLock)
                    {
                        depth--;
                    }
                }, item);

                int d = 0;
                lock (padLock)
                {
                    d = depth;
                }

                while (d >= maxDegreeOfParallelization)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                    lock (padLock)
                    {
                        d = depth;
                    }
                }

                task.Start(TaskScheduler.Current);

                lock (padLock)
                {
                    depth++;
                }
            }

            var dd = 0;

            lock (padLock)
            {
                dd = depth;
            }

            while (dd > 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                lock (padLock)
                {
                    dd = depth;
                }
            }

            _continuation?.Invoke(_results.Values);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Point-in-time results providing a stable result set
        /// for processing results as the block runs.
        /// </summary>
        public ConcurrentDictionary<TData, (TData data, TResult result)?> Results
        {
            get
            {
                var results = new ConcurrentDictionary<TData, (TData data, TResult result)?>();

                foreach (var key in _results.Keys)
                {
                    var result = _results[key];
                    var value = key;

                    results.AddOrUpdate(value, result, (resultKey, resultValue) => resultValue);
                }

                return results;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would be very grateful for feedback on the features, design and implementation.

A simple usage is

```
        [Fact]
        public void ContrivedTest()
        {
            string Processor(int data)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(data);
                return $"Waiting {data} miliseconds";
            }

            void Warmup(int data)
            {
                _log.WriteLine($"Contrived Warmup for {data}");
            }

            void ThreadBlockContinuation(Task task, (int data, string result)? result)
            {
                _log.WriteLine($"Contrived Thread Continuation result: {result.Value.data}, {result.Value.result}");
            }

            void PLINQContinuation((int data, string result)? result)
            {
                _log.WriteLine($"Contrived Thread Continuation result: {result.Value.data}, {result.Value.result}");
            }

            void BlockContinuation(ICollection<(int data, string result)?> results)
            {
                _log.WriteLine($"Results count: {results.Count}");
            }

            var dataSet = new int[500];

            var rand = new System.Random();

            for(int i = 0; i < dataSet.Length; ++i)
            {
                dataSet[i] = rand.Next(250, 2500);
            }

            var block = new ThreadBlock<int, string>(
                Processor,
                BlockContinuation);

            block.AddRange(dataSet);

            block.LockList();

            var parallelism = 8;

            var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            block.Execute(parallelism, Warmup, ThreadBlockContinuation);

            sw.Stop();
            var blockElapsed = sw.Elapsed;

            sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

            sw.Start();

            var resultSet = dataSet
                .Select(data => { Warmup(data); return data; })
                .AsParallel()
                .WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(parallelism)
                .Select(data => 
                {
                        return new Nullable<(int data, string result)>
                            ((data: data, result: Processor(data)));
                })
                .AsSequential()
                .Select(result => {
                    PLINQContinuation(result);
                    return result;
                }).ToList();

            BlockContinuation(resultSet.ToArray());

            sw.Stop();
            var plinqElapsed = sw.Elapsed;

            _log.WriteLine(
                $"block: {blockElapsed.TotalSeconds}, " + 
                $"PLINQ: {plinqElapsed.TotalSeconds}");

            Assert.Equal(dataSet.Length, block.Results.Count);
            Assert.Equal(dataSet.Length, resultSet.Count);

            // This is here to force the test to fail
            // allowing dotnet test to output the log.
            Assert.Equal(blockElapsed, plinqElapsed);
        }
```

### Edit 2

Added a PLINQ equivalent to the test.  Execution times
are practically identitical.  To me, the PLINQ version
is a mess.

So it really comes down to what you like better.

Here's an example result from my system using the 
exact test above:

```
... lots of data ....
 Contrived Thread Continuation result: 1143, Waiting 1143 miliseconds
 Contrived Thread Continuation result: 1593, Waiting 1593 miliseconds
 Contrived Thread Continuation result: 2206, Waiting 2206 miliseconds
 Results count: 500
 block: 84.4324359, PLINQ: 85.2551954
```

The data is meant to simulate a large set of expensive operations, which is the natural use-case for parallelism.  All parameters and data are identical between the ThreadBlock and PLINQ tests.

Comment: When you do embed the code (and fix the example), perhaps you could also explain the intended use-case for this class? It seems relatively inefficient compared to an equivalent PLINQ approach.

Comment: I would love to know the PLINQ alternative.  Can you explain?

Comment: OK, read up on the PLINQ, there's definitely some overlap.  I will do some testing and see which methodology is faster.

Comment: The PLINQ "equivalent" of a Thread Continuation has a few drawbacks:

* It has to be run in a second pass through the data
* There is no Task result to get state about the task.  This is a biggie.

Comment: I'd consider those tasks to be an implementation detail - why would you need to expose them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  I already have a use case that the ThreadBlock serves perfectly.  I'm actually going to make the Lock optional so that the ThreadBlock can run continuously and automatically process data as it comes in once Execute has been called.  I will need to add a Stop method and make Execute return Task<void> so it can be awaited or run asynchronously.  I also need to add cancellation tokens.

Answer (score 2):

#### Design

I think there are some problems with this design:

- `ThreadBlock` has too many responsibilities: it's used to build a read-only collection, to perform parallelized work on it and to store the results of that work. That's a fairly rigid workflow. PLINQ, in comparison, is much more composable: you can call `AsParallel().Select(DoWork)` on anything that's enumerable, and the results are returned directly to the caller, which can then store, share, discard or further process them depending on the use-case (without the risk that something else will overwrite these results).
- The design is conflicting: because `action` and `continuation` are passed to the constructor, `Execute` should always perform the same work, so it doesn't make sense to call it multiple times (you'd just be redoing work that was already done*). On the other hand, `Execute` accepts per-item warmup and continuation callbacks, which allow custom work (or rather, side-effects, because they don't return anything) per `Execute` call. How is this intended to be used? Why so many different callbacks?
- All that sleeping and locking in `Execute` looks quite inefficient. This may not always be noticeable - it depends on the amount of items and how much work needs to be done per item - but I'm fairly sure PLINQ is better optimized in this regard.

I think the PLINQ equivalent is mostly just messy because the overal workflow is messy, with several separate callbacks being used for side-effects (I'd use loops for that, not `Select` calls). Why not move that extra work into `Processor`? That would make both the PLINQ approach and the design of your `ThreadBlock` class simpler.

Note that `ThreadBlock` is running the warmup and thread continuations in parallel, while your PLINQ example runs them sequentially.

---

**Unless that work is not deterministic, but I'm not sure that that's such a good idea. You'd run into trouble with `Results`, as you can't tell whether a result is new or old while an `Execute` call is still in progress.*

#### Other problems

- `Results` does not take duplicate `TData` values into account - it silently discards the results of all but one of them.
- `Execute` gets stuck on `null` data items. `ConcurrentDictionary` throws when you're trying to use `null` as a key, which then causes `depth` to not be decreased.
- `Add` and `AddRange` silently discard their input once `LockList` has been called. I would at least expect an exception to be thrown.

#### Other notes

- Some quick testing suggests that adding items to a bag in parallel is slower than doing so sequentially.
- Both `ICollection<T>` and `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` implement `IEnumerable<T>`, so those `AddRange` overloads aren't needed.
- I think `TInput` is a little more self-descriptive than `TData`.
- Why does the thread continuation take a nullable tuple? It's never invoked with null.
- Why is `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` publicly settable? Mutable shared state is best avoided in concurrency. This makes it possible for another thread to 'intercept' the degree of parallelism.
- Why use `task.ContinueWith` if you can call both `action` and `threadContinuation` inside the original task?
- Why expose this task to `threadContinuation`? Whether your `ThreadBlock` uses threads, tasks or some other approach internally shouldn't matter to outside code. This prevents you from switching to a different implementation without affecting existing callers.
- You may want to verify that `action` isn't null in the constructor, and throw an `ArgumentNullException` if it is.
- It's recommended to make custom exception types serializable.

Comment: Thank you! I see several places to make the implementation better from your comments.  The fact that the `threadContinuation` runs on the main thread, not the task, is very important as it's meant to be the equivalent behavior of calling `ContinueWith` directly on a `Task`.

Exposing the `Task` to the `threadContinutation` is again part of implementing the `ContinueWith` pattern.  It makes going from implicitly declaring `Tasks` to a `ThreadBlock `an apples-to-apples implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? `threadContinuation` is not executed on the thread that's calling `Execute`. `task.ContinueWith` creates a second task that will be scheduled after `task` is finished. It might well be executed on the same thread as the preceding task, or on a different thread - that's up to the task scheduler.